# Why AJAX dont´t pass value of name from html File-(JS part) to PHP File using POST?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I tried to pass value of name from .js file to PHP using POST method. But when I start the code, there isn´t any alert.
In console is only: *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined* 
Do you know what could be improved?

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


const name = "asdasd";

$.ajax({
  url: "TargetFile.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    name
  },
  success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
  },
  error: function (error) {
    alert("Error " + error.status);
  }
})
    
</script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  if (empty($name)) {
    echo "Name is empty";
  } else {
    echo $name;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: the data payload that you are trying to send is not a valid object literal - it should be a `name` / `value` pair

Comment: But I have defined value before. Do you think I can´t do that by this way?

Comment: Should be `data: { name: name}` but the error indicates jquery is not defined/included.

Comment: Thank´s but problem still persists..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple, single page, test script that will send a POST request to the server which sends the response for the ajax callback. As others have stated - you should include the jQuery library but you need to change the payload to a valid object literal. The POST request expects `name=value` pairs as per below.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        $result=!empty( $_POST['name'] ) ? $_POST['name'] : 'Name is empty';
        exit( $result );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Basic jQuery Ajax POST</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
        
            const name = "Geronimo frequently kicked ass";

            $.ajax({
              url: location.href,   //"TargetFile.php"
              method: "POST",
              data: {
                'name':name
              },
              success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
              },
              error: function(error) {
                alert("Error " + error.status);
              }
            })      
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Using 2 separate scripts, one that makes the request (index.html) and the other that processes the request and sends the response (targetfile.php)

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Basic jQuery Ajax POST</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
        
            const name = "Geronimo kicked ass";

            $.ajax({
              url: "TargetFile.php",
              method: "POST",
              data: {
                'name':name
              },
              success: function(result) {
                console.log( result )
              },
              error: function(error) {
                alert("Error " + error.status);
              }
            })      
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

### targetfile.php

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        $result=!empty( $_POST['name'] ) ? $_POST['name'] : 'Name is empty';
        exit( $result );
    }
?>
```

Both scripts in same directory, request is made OK and console message is displayed ( removed annoying `alert` )

Comment: This code display php code in page and full code as the alert.

Comment: not as it is written above it does not... It will simply popup the alert with the message about Geronimo! This was tested as it appears above

Comment: Sorry, now i see it is correct, but when I created net php file with same code, and referred for that in JS part, it is not running anymore.

Comment: You would need to add that php script that you mention in order that we can identify what is causing your peculiar behaviour. Was it saved as `.php` or `.html`?

Comment: When I removed php part, I changed it as _.html_ .

Comment: The target used in the ajax request should be a php file not html. The script making the request can be either php or html, I simply added the PHP code to the same script to demonstrate a single (php) page app that sends the ajax request to itself... I apologise if that was not clear. If you are using an external PHP script `TargetFile.php` then change the `url: location.href,` to `url: "TargetFile.php",` as per your original and try

Comment: Yes, TargetFile is PHP, I talked about the first with ajax code.

Comment: did you change the ajax function url to point to that PHP script?

Comment: Yes, I changed to TargetFile.php

Comment: Now it works and how to see that it is in php file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the jQuery lib before using it. And also the head tag should be outside of the body tag.

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


           const name = "asdasd";

           $.ajax({
               url: "TargetFile.php",
               method: "POST",
               data: {
                   name
               },
               success: function (result) {
                   alert(result);
               },
               error: function (error) {
                   alert("Error " + error.status);
               }
           })

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but I still don´t see anything.

Comment: _Test.html_ : https://ibb.co/K67ZTNN, _TargetFile.php_ : https://ibb.co/qmgfz2t Textuploaders block codes, StackOverflow does not allow longer codes in comments.

Comment: Have you tried this codes?

Comment: Please post the request header and params you'll find in your browser console. You also could just var_dump($_REQUEST) to see all request parameters, this might help.